# How to change the default username of Git

Tags: git, bitbucket

When I'm trying to push my code using `git push origin master` it ask me the password for `'https://test_ankit@bitbucket.org'` but my actual username is 'rest_ankit'.

I've used this command to change it 'git config --global user.name "rest_ankit"', but it didn't work.
its still asking password for wrong username, and showing authentication failed.
Plz help me out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the url of origin with:

```
git remote set-url https://rest_ankit@bitbucket.org/username/reponame.git
```

That will change the username associated with the url as well.
Use the full url of your repo, not just `bitbucket.org`, but `bitbucket.org/username/reponame.git`, replacing `username` and `reponame` with the right values.

---

Note that the http credentials has nothing to do with `git config user.name`: the latter is user for commit authorship, not for authentication during push/pull.

Git 2.25.1 (Feb. 2020) clarifies the documentation on committer/author identities.

See [commit 69e104d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/69e104d70e29060742c75ccdcb6653e23c65f3c3), [commit 813f602](https://github.com/git/git/commit/813f6025a5094bc27df879eb0152441c4157c47e), [commit bc94e58](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bc94e5862aed854c77d4f96da9447161ce84a824) (22 Jan 2020) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c9ccf9d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c9ccf9d09b3aa179b198774afb720e229b544f45), 30 Jan 2020)</sup>
[Discussed here](https://public-inbox.org/git/20200122034543.18927-1-sandals@crustytoothpaste.net/T/#u).

> ### [`doc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/69e104d70e29060742c75ccdcb6653e23c65f3c3): provide guidance on user.name format
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: brian m. carlson</sup>
>
> It's a frequent misconception that the **`user.name`** variable controls authentication in some way, and as a result, beginning users frequently attempt to change it when they're having authentication troubles.
>   Document that the convention is that this variable represents some form of a human's personal name, although that is not required.
>
> In addition, address concerns about whether Unicode is supported.
>
> Use the term "personal name" as this is likely to draw the intended contrast, be applicable across cultures which may have different naming conventions, and be easily understandable to people who do not speak English as their first language.
>
> Indicate that "some form" is conventionally used, as people may use a nickname or preferred name instead of a full legal name.
>
> Point users who may be confused about authentication to an appropriate configuration option instead.
>
> Provide a shortened form of this information in the configuration option description.

so the [git config user man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c9ccf9d09b3aa179b198774afb720e229b544f45/Documentation/config/user.txt#L17-L21) does explain that:

> the `name` forms of these variables conventionally refer to some form of a personal name.

And [`git commit`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c9ccf9d09b3aa179b198774afb720e229b544f45/Documentation/git-commit.txt#L452-L482) includes:

> ### COMMIT INFORMATION
>
> Author and committer information is taken from the following environment
>   variables, if set:
>
> ```
> GIT_AUTHOR_NAME
> GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL
> GIT_AUTHOR_DATE
> GIT_COMMITTER_NAME
> GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL
> GIT_COMMITTER_DATE
> ```
>
> (nb "`<`", "`>`" and "`\n`"s are stripped)
>
> The author and committer names are by convention some form of a personal name
>   (that is, the name by which other humans refer to you), although Git does not
>   enforce or require any particular form.
>   Arbitrary Unicode may be used, subject to the constraints listed above.
>   This name has no effect on authentication; for that, see the [`credential.username`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-credentialusername) variable, used in [gitcredentials](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials).

Comment: fatal: https://rest_ankit@bitbucket.org/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

Comment: @Ankit you need to full url of your repo: https://rest_ankit@bitbucket.org/username/reponame

Comment: Can this also be done without changing the URL of the origin - but just by the key or similar?
I have a git with 50 submodules where it's not applicable to change the URLs of each submodule to match my username - because of a lot of workers in the team...

Comment: @Micha yes: in the parent repo: `git config --global url."https://myusername@github".insteadOf https://github`

Comment: @VonC Cool! That's an improvement for my local setup, maybe I can even get rid of the password prompts by switch to git@ syntax.The problem with the submodules I could work around using relative URLs.

Answer (score 4):

ssh

```
git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:{new team or account name}/{repository name}.git
```

https

```
git remote set-url origin https://{username}@bitbucket.org/{new team or account name}/{repository name}.git
```

then check the changes using

```
git remote -v
```

if u have problems while pushing and the remote of push has not changed then type

for ssh

```
git remote set-url --push origin git@bitbucket.org:{new team or account name}/{repository name}.git
```

for https

```
git remote set-url --push origin https://{username}@bitbucket.org/{new team or account name}/{repository name}.git
```

Comment: This works for me. The accepted answer has `origin` missing